# Ordering a Delimited Column by Section

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to order a column sequentially by each delimited section. For example, given the sample data:

```
    a   
----------
120.1
120.2
120.12
120
130
120.2.22
120.2.41
120.3
```

I need to obtain the following output:

```
120
120.1
120.2
120.2.22
120.2.41
120.3
120.12
130
```

I use this query but its doesn't work

Query ;

```
Select a from b rpad(REPLACE(a, '.', ''),15,0),REPLACE(a, '.', '') ASC
```

Comment: why is 120.3 before 120.12

Comment: The reason is because you are cramming multiple values into a single column and then expecting the result to be ordered correctly. The best solution would be to fix your data structure. Is everything numeric? Meaning you don't have any character data at all?

Comment: @scsimon because 3 < 12. They want to sort strings but use numeric sorting rules.

Comment: @SeanLange Sir, i dont know the point values. i cant insert it on column by column. Because user can insert a value like 22.33 and the user can insert 2.13.44.22.1.7.8.2.34.2 the point unlimited.

Comment: You're probably better off handling this client-side. I would say you could make use of [SUBSTRING_INDEX](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) a lot; but the varying number of segments is going to make that very very unwieldy. _Nevermind, just noticed the MySQL tag was removed; there may be better options in MS SQL._

Comment: OUCH!!! So then I am guessing you very likely have some values that are also no numbers. You have a really horrible thing here. You will have to use a string splitter to isolate each value first. I would suggest using Jeff Moden's because it has ordinal position. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/. Then do a TRY_CONVERT on each value to see if they are integers and put the sorted integers first, followed by sorted non-integers. Repeat this for each level. This is NOT going to be easy or fast.

Comment: A string splitter function (strtok, substring_index like) in a recursive statement to peel each piece apart and pad out with zeros, then stitch back together, then sort. It won't be pretty or fast.

Comment: Which is the datatype of the column A and which collation is your DB using using ? You should have a correct sort by simply using "Select a from b order by a" in case the column is declared as varchar

Comment: And it's not so much that it's "horrible" data or schema or architecture. I can totally understand having a value stored like this and needing to sort in this way (bin locations in a warehouse, for instance). But...  it is horrible to solve for, especially in sql server which lacks a `strtok` like function or the ability to split that `strtok` out to a table. Thinking `strtok_split_to_table` in Teradata, pad with zeros, `listagg`, `group_concat`, `xmlagg` back together and sort to get out of the need for recursive.

Comment: thanks for the clarrificaiton @SeanLange

Answer (score 3):

I agree with all the comments from [Sean Lange](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3813116/sean-lange) et al. Since you can have unlimited number of decimals, you need a splitter. Once the values are split, then you could apply the same `ORDER BY` logic I have shown. I think the `ORDER BY` really explains the *algorithm* you were looking for.

Here is a way with a [splitter](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/):

```
declare @table table (col varchar(64))
insert into @table
values
('120.1'),
('120.2'),
('120.12'),
('120'),
('130'),
('120.2.22'),
('120.2.41.55.64.12'),
('120.3')

;with cte as(
select
    *
from @table t 
cross apply dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(t.col,'.')
pivot(
max(Item) for ItemNumber in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8]) --enter the number of possibilities
) p)

select 
    cte.*
from cte
order by
    cast(isnull(cte.[1],0) as int)
    ,cast(isnull(cte.[2],0) as int)
    ,cast(isnull(cte.[3],0) as int)
    ,cast(isnull(cte.[4],0) as int)
    ,cast(isnull(cte.[5],0) as int)
    ,cast(isnull(cte.[6],0) as int)
    ,cast(isnull(cte.[7],0) as int)
    ,cast(isnull(cte.[8],0) as int)
```

**The function, if needed:**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[DelimitedSplit8K] (@pString VARCHAR(8000), @pDelimiter CHAR(1))
--WARNING!!! DO NOT USE MAX DATA-TYPES HERE!  IT WILL KILL PERFORMANCE!

RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
RETURN

/* "Inline" CTE Driven "Tally Table" produces values from 1 up to 10,000... enough to cover VARCHAR(8000)*/

  WITH E1(N) AS (
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
                ),                          --10E+1 or 10 rows
       E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
       E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
 cteTally(N) AS (--==== This provides the "base" CTE and limits the number of rows right up front
                     -- for both a performance gain and prevention of accidental "overruns"
                 SELECT TOP (ISNULL(DATALENGTH(@pString),0)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
                ),
cteStart(N1) AS (--==== This returns N+1 (starting position of each "element" just once for each delimiter)
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT t.N+1 FROM cteTally t WHERE SUBSTRING(@pString,t.N,1) = @pDelimiter
                ),
cteLen(N1,L1) AS(--==== Return start and length (for use in substring)
                 SELECT s.N1,
                        ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@pDelimiter,@pString,s.N1),0)-s.N1,8000)
                   FROM cteStart s
                )
--===== Do the actual split. The ISNULL/NULLIF combo handles the length for the final element when no delimiter is found.
 SELECT ItemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY l.N1),
        Item       = SUBSTRING(@pString, l.N1, l.L1)
   FROM cteLen l


GO
```

Comment: You would have to cast as int instead of varchar. This is close but still doesn't quite do it. For example 120.2.22 sorts above 120.1

Comment: You seem to be having the same challenges as I am. This does not get the order correct. Look at 130 and then 120.2.22. But....flipping the order by "upside down" does it. Order by 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8

Comment: fixed @SeanLange

Comment: Like you @SeanLange i only took interest because i have seen this before but couldn't remember a good solution.

Comment: Yes and yours was a good solution. I was close but the pivot is what took it to the finish line. I added your script to my code snippet library. I will of course give you credit when and if I post a solution using that again. Well done.

Answer (score 0):

First create a function to split. I stole this one from https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

```
create FUNCTION dbo.SplitStrings_XML
(
   @List       NVARCHAR(MAX),
   @Delimiter  NVARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
   RETURN 
   (  
      SELECT rn=row_number() over (order by i), Item = y.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'nvarchar(4000)')
      FROM 
      ( 
        SELECT x = CONVERT(XML, '<i>' 
          + REPLACE(@List, @Delimiter, '</i><i>') 
          + '</i>').query('.')
      ) AS a CROSS APPLY x.nodes('i') AS y(i)
   );
GO


declare @t table (a varchar(64))
insert into @t
values
('120.1'),
('120.2'),
('120.12'),
('120'),
('130'),
('120.2.22'),
('120.2.41'),
('120.3')


select a
    , a1 = max(cast(case when rn=1 then Item else null end as int))
    , a2 = max(cast(case when rn=2 then Item else null end as int))
    , a3 = max(cast(case when rn=3 then Item else null end as int))
    , a4 = max(cast(case when rn=4 then Item else null end as int))
from @t t
    cross apply dbo.SplitStrings_XML(t.a,'.') as a
group by t.a
order by 2,3,4,5
```